# Two columns next to one other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I currently have two Divs next to each one big div like this:

[image]

The reason why I don't use a row instead of putting every div as a single one is that I need "DIV2" in the Mobile version to be between the two other divs.

But the big space between DIV1 and DIV3 ruins everything, how can i remove the spacing without losing my wanted layout?

HTML Code:

```html
      <div class="DIV1 col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8" />
      <div class="DIV2 col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" />
      <div class="DIV3 col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8" />
```

I use the standard Bootstrap code for the styling

Comment: You should put your div1 and div3 inside a div and then it should work
like <div class="hold13"><div1/><div3/></div><div2></div2>

Comment: Yeah but then i have the problem that on the mobile view "DIV3" is not in the middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is do is add float to your divs via the class `pull-left` or `pull-right` provided by bootstrap.  This will make DIV3 take up the big space.

Check out the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/80r028jq/1/

Comment: Thank you very much :) It's working perfectly as it should and you made my day. I tried to use the float property seperately but it didn't worked, maybe i should learn a bit more about Bootstrap

Comment: Sure thing! Bootstrap is awesome, you won't regret learning more of it!

Comment: Yeah I definitely gonna do it :) It's just a big framework ^^

Answer (score 0):

Both `div1` and `div3` should be in the same column so put these in a another div and than you can use `display:inline-block` or `display:flex-box;`

```
<div class="fl">
<div class="div1">
<div class="DIV1 col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8" />
  <div class="DIV3 col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8" />
</div>
  <div class="DIV2 col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" />
</div>

.fl
{
display:flex-box;
}
```